# Summarize time from a log file

Tags: bash, date, awk, sed

I need a script to work with a file and summarize the outages from SLA probe. The file I have is following:

`Jan 28 22:10:02 test-195869-st28
Jan 28 22:10:04 test-195869-st28
Jan 28 22:10:06 test-195869-st28
Jan 28 22:10:08 test-195869-st28
Jan 28 22:10:10 test-195869-st28
Jan 28 22:10:12 test-195869-st28
Jan 28 22:10:14 test-195869-st28
Jan 28 22:15:16 test-195869-st28
Jan 28 23:12:34 test-195869-st28
Jan 28 23:12:36 test-195869-st28
Jan 28 23:12:38 test-195869-st28
Jan 28 23:12:40 test-195869-st28
Jan 28 23:12:42 test-195869-st28
Jan 28 23:12:44 test-195869-st28
Jan 28 23:12:46 test-195869-st28
Jan 28 23:12:48 test-195869-st28
Jan 28 23:12:50 test-195869-st28
Jan 28 23:12:52 test-195869-st28
Jan 29 13:12:18 test-195869-st28
Jan 29 13:12:20 test-195869-st28
Jan 29 13:12:22 test-195869-st28
Jan 29 13:12:24 test-195869-st28
Jan 29 13:12:26 test-195869-st28
Jan 29 13:12:28 test-195869-st28
Jan 29 13:12:30 test-195869-st28
Jan 29 13:12:32 test-195869-st28
Jan 29 13:12:34 test-195869-st28
Jan 29 13:12:36 test-195869-st28`

The desired output is following

```
Jan 28 22:10:02 test-195869-st28  
...  
Jan 28 22:10:14 test-195869-st28

Jan 28 22:15:16 test-195869-st28

Jan 28 23:12:34 test-195869-st28  
...  
Jan 29 13:12:36 test-195869-st28
```

All outages should be summarized (everything falling in single 30 seconds interval is single outage). However there are single second outages which should remain in the log as single entries.

Till now I was trying to do that with awk reading from file:

```
 awk 'BEGIN{prevDt=0;}
 {
  getDate="date -d \""$1" "$2" "$3"\" \"+%s\""
  print "Get date:" (getDate);
      while ( ( getDate | getline date ) > 0 ) {
  Diff=date-prevDt
  prevDt=date;
  print "Difference: "Diff" "$1" "$2" "$3" "$12;
 }
      close(getDate);

  } END { print $date }'
```

I was thinking to use that difference for later comparison.

Thank you

Comment: At a minimum edit your question to format your sample input and output using the `{}` editor button and provide what you've tried so far. Get rid of all the `...`s and anything else that would make your sample input/output untestable.

Comment: So you want lines that just contain `...` in your output, right? Do you have or can you get GNU awk? Why are `Jan 28 23:12:34 test-195869-st28  ...  Jan 29 13:12:36 test-195869-st28` grouped in the output as if they were a 30 second range? What would the output be if the input had overlapping timestamps, e.g. `10:20:00 ... 10:20:20 ... 10:20:40`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what logic you want to employ when there's overlap between timestamps withing 30 sec intervals so here's how to create an array of timestamps with GNU awk and use it as you like:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
    year  = strftime("%Y")
    month = (match("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",$1)+2)/3
    day   = $2
    time  = gensub(/:/," ","g",$3)
    secs  = mktime(year" "month" "day" "time)

    print year, month, day, time, "=>", secs
    outages[NR] = secs FS $0
    next
}
{
    # loop through "outages" starting at current
    # line number to find those with first value
    # (secs) within 30 of the current value.
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
2016 1 28 22 10 02 => 1454040602
2016 1 28 22 10 04 => 1454040604
2016 1 28 22 10 06 => 1454040606
2016 1 28 22 10 08 => 1454040608
2016 1 28 22 10 10 => 1454040610
2016 1 28 22 10 12 => 1454040612
2016 1 28 22 10 14 => 1454040614
2016 1 28 22 15 16 => 1454040916
2016 1 28 23 12 34 => 1454044354
2016 1 28 23 12 36 => 1454044356
2016 1 28 23 12 38 => 1454044358
2016 1 28 23 12 40 => 1454044360
2016 1 28 23 12 42 => 1454044362
2016 1 28 23 12 44 => 1454044364
2016 1 28 23 12 46 => 1454044366
2016 1 28 23 12 48 => 1454044368
2016 1 28 23 12 50 => 1454044370
2016 1 28 23 12 52 => 1454044372
2016 1 29 13 12 18 => 1454094738
2016 1 29 13 12 20 => 1454094740
2016 1 29 13 12 22 => 1454094742
2016 1 29 13 12 24 => 1454094744
2016 1 29 13 12 26 => 1454094746
2016 1 29 13 12 28 => 1454094748
2016 1 29 13 12 30 => 1454094750
2016 1 29 13 12 32 => 1454094752
2016 1 29 13 12 34 => 1454094754
2016 1 29 13 12 36 => 1454094756
```

Comment out the current `print` line when you've got your final logic in place.

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you want:

```
#!/bin/bash

LogFile="mylog.log"

function Get-LineDate(){
    local Line="$1"
    if [[ "$Line" != "" ]]; then
        local LineDate=$(grep -oP ".*(?= test)" <<< "$Line")
        local LineDate=$(date -d "$LineDate" +"%s")
        echo "$LineDate"
    fi
}

function Get-DateDiff(){
    local DateOne="$1"
    local DateTwo="$2"

    if [[ "$DateOne" != "" ]] && [[ "$DateTwo" != "" ]]; then
        local DateDiff=$(( $DateOne -$DateTwo))
        echo "$DateDiff"
    fi
}


count=0
while read -r line; do
    if [[ "$count" -eq 0 ]]; then
        prevline="$line"
        prevdate=$(Get-LineDate "$line")
        echo "$line"
        count="1"
    else 
        linedate=$(Get-LineDate "$line")
        datediff=$(Get-DateDiff "$linedate" "$prevdate")
        if [[ "$datediff" -ge 30 ]]; then
            echo "$prevline -> $line - Interval: $datediff (seconds)"
        fi
        prevline="$line"
        prevdate="$linedate"
    fi
done < $LogFile
```

Output with full summary:

```
Jan 28 22:10:02 test-195869-st28
Jan 28 22:10:14 test-195869-st28 -> Jan 28 22:15:16 test-195869-st28 - Interval: 302 (seconds)
Jan 28 22:15:16 test-195869-st28 -> Jan 28 23:12:34 test-195869-st28 - Interval: 3438 (seconds)
Jan 28 23:12:52 test-195869-st28 -> Jan 29 13:12:18 test-195869-st28 - Interval: 50366 (seconds)
```

If you want your exact output would need to change the while loop/logic to:

```
   while read -r line; do
    if [[ "$count" -eq 0 ]]; then
        prevline="$line"
        prevdate=$(Get-LineDate "$line")
        LineArr+=("$line")
        echo "$line"
    else 
        linedate=$(Get-LineDate "$line")
        datediff=$(Get-DateDiff "$linedate" "$prevdate")
        if [[ "$datediff" -ge 30 ]]; then
            for item in "${LineArr[@]}"; do
                if  [[ "$item" == "$prevline" ]]; then
                    bit=1
                    break
                fi  
            done
            if [[ "$bit" != "1" ]]; then 
                echo "$prevline"
                LineArr+=("$prevline")
            else
                bit=""
            fi

            for item in "${LineArr[@]}"; do
                if  [[ "$item" == "$line" ]]; then
                    bit=1
                    break
                fi  
            done
            if [[ "$bit" != "1" ]]; then 
                echo "$line"
                LineArr+=("$line")
            else
                bit=""
            fi
        fi
        prevline="$line"
        prevdate="$linedate"
    fi
    count=$(( $count +1 ))
done < $LogFile
```

Outputs:

```
Jan 28 22:10:02 test-195869-st28
Jan 28 22:10:14 test-195869-st28
Jan 28 22:15:16 test-195869-st28
Jan 28 23:12:34 test-195869-st28
Jan 28 23:12:52 test-195869-st28
Jan 29 13:12:18 test-195869-st28
```

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice

Answer (score 1):

Here is the final code:

```
#!/bin/bash

LogFile="test"


function Get-LineDate(){
    local Line="$1"
    if [[ "$Line" != "" ]]; then
        local LineDate=$(grep -oP ".*(?= MGIM0-test)" <<< "$Line")
        local LineDate=$(date -d "$LineDate" +"%s")
        echo "$LineDate"
    fi
}

function Get-DateDiff(){
    local DateOne="$1"
    local DateTwo="$2"

    if [[ "$DateOne" != "" ]] && [[ "$DateTwo" != "" ]]; then
        local DateDiff=$(( $DateOne -$DateTwo))
        echo "$DateDiff"
    fi
}

count=0
interval=0
prev_int=0

while read -r line; do
    if [[ "$count" -eq 0 ]]; then
        prevline="$line"
        prevdate=$(Get-LineDate "$line")
       # echo "$line"
        count="1"
        start_int="$line"
    else 
        linedate=$(Get-LineDate "$line")
        datediff=$(Get-DateDiff "$linedate" "$prevdate")
        prev_int=$interval 
        interval=$(( $datediff + $interval ))
    #   echo "Interval: $interval Previnterval: $prev_int"
    if [[ "$interval" -gt "$(( $prev_int+30 ))" ]] && [[ "$prev_int" -eq "0" ]]; then
        echo "$start_int - Single seconds outage"
        start_int="$line"

    fi
    if [[ "$interval" -gt "$(( $prev_int+30 ))" ]]; then
        echo -e "$start_int \n ... \n$prevline"
#       echo "$start_int -> $prevline - Interval: $prev_int (seconds)
        start_int="$line"
        interval=0
        prev_int=0
        fi

 #       if [[ "$datediff" -ge 30 ]]; then
  #          echo "$prevline -> $line - Interval: $datediff (seconds)"
       # fi
        prevline="$line"
        prevdate="$linedate"
    fi

done < $LogFile

if [[ "$start_int" ==  "$prevline" ]]; then
 echo "$start_int - Single seconds outage"
else
 echo "$start_int -> $prevline"
fi
```

Thanks all !